# python sum and merge element of list

Tags: python, list, datetime, sum

I have some list like this

```
[ ['2000-01-01', 1.0], ['2000-02-01', 2.0] ]
[ ['2000-01-01', 2.0], ['2000-02-01', 1.0], ['2000-03-01', 3.0] ]
[ ['2000-01-01', 3.1], ['2000-02-01', 2.0], ['2000-03-01', 1.4] ]
```

how can i merge the datatime and sum the value get a list like this

```
[ ['2000-01-01', 6.1], ['2000-02-01', 5.0], ['2000-03-01', 4.4] ]
```

the element's type in list is [datetime, double]

Comment: Using a dictionary type, or at least a list of tuples would much make more sense for this use case. Also, this can be considered a classic map reduce problem. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here. See the snippet.

```
>>> a = [ ['2000-01-01', 1.0], ['2000-02-01', 2.0] ]
>>> b = [ ['2000-01-01', 2.0], ['2000-02-01', 1.0], ['2000-03-01', 3.0] ]
>>> c = [ ['2000-01-01', 3.0], ['2000-02-01', 2.0], ['2000-03-01', 1.0] ]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> m = defaultdict(int)
>>> d = a + b + c
>>> d
[['2000-01-01', 1.0], ['2000-02-01', 2.0], ['2000-01-01', 2.0], ['2000-02-01', 1.0], ['2000-03-01', 3.0], ['2000-01-01', 3.0], ['2000-02-01', 2.0], ['2000-03-01', 1.0]]
>>> for date, count in d:
        m[date] += count
>>> m.items()
[('2000-02-01', 5.0), ('2000-03-01', 4.0), ('2000-01-01', 6.0)]
```

Comment: His solution calls for use with type double. You provide solution with type int. Please update your answer.

Comment: @pygeek : That doesn't really matter in the context of the question. He had posted an integer before. The solution works for both types. Updated nevertheless. :)

Answer (score 0):

For all that kind of Excel-like programming, I advise to leverage Pandas as it is made for this.
However if you want to stay with the standard lib, a Counter is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use [counter.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter()
result += Counter(dict([ ['2000-01-01', 1], ['2000-02-01', 2] ]))
result += Counter(dict([ ['2000-01-01', 2], ['2000-02-01', 1], ['2000-03-01', 3] ]))
result += Counter(dict([ ['2000-01-01', 3], ['2000-02-01', 2], ['2000-03-01', 1] ]))
result.most_common() # => [('2000-01-01', 6), ('2000-02-01', 5), ('2000-03-01', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
#inputList is List containg 
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

def mergeAndGetSum(inputList):
    cnt = Counter()

    #get counts for each date
    for list1 in inputList:
        for list2 in list1:
            cnt[list2[0]] += list2[1]
    ret = []

    #creaet the output list
    for key in cnt:
        ret.append([key,cnt[key]])

    #sort output list based on dates
    ret.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
    return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    listOfLists = [
            [ ['2000-01-01', 1], ['2000-02-01', 2] ],
            [ ['2000-01-01', 2], ['2000-02-01', 1], ['2000-03-01', 3] ],
            [ ['2000-01-01', 3], ['2000-02-01', 2], ['2000-03-01', 1] ]
            ]
    ret = mergeAndGetSum(listOfLists)
    print ret
```